# What type of equation is this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Is this equation an ODE or PDE

$$ \frac{d^3u}{dx^3}−αxu=0, x∈R $$

The only thing given is $\int_R u(x) =\pi $ and $α>0$ is some constant.

I have to find the solution using fourier transformation but  we've only ever learnt for PDE since it is a PDE class.

Comment: this is a ode. Only one independent variable.

Comment: It is also linear.